# Redirect 301 and looping

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect

I just moved static html site to joomla based and I need a small support with htaccess:

Old link was `xxxx.com/en/links.htm` -> `xxxx.com/en/links` but I get looping error

my configuration:

```
Redirect 301 /en/links.htm http://www.xxxx.com/en/links
```

It works well, when I redirect to different destination folder that /en but when I redirect to the same folder I get looping error. Anyone knows how to solve that issue?

best regards!

Comment: do you also have a rewrite rule that sends `/en/links` to `/en/links.html`?

Comment: No, this is the only rule.

Comment: Then maybe your web server has the default document for the `en/links` folder set to be `links.html`

Comment: It defaults to index.php - default Joomla config.

Comment: http://www.atriumaparthotel.pl/htaccess.txt - here's txt version of my htaccess file

Comment: Any ideas Guys? All comments appreciated!

Comment: I tried one link and it returned a 404. Can you make at least one "work" (meaning to manifest the redirect loop)?

Comment: Try now - I added such redirect to htaccess: 
Redirect 301 /pl/main.htm http://atriumaparthotel.pl/pl/

Comment: Now I can't read the htaccess file anymore :)

Comment: OK, I reversed changes. Try now to view that file:
atriumaparthotel.pl/htaccess.txt
Thanks in advance for Your time and help!

Comment: When do you get 404? when you try to get htaccess.txt?

Comment: yes, it redirects to http://www.atriumaparthotel.pl/pl/main.htm that says 404 - Artykułu nie znaleziono

Comment: clear your cache :) It should fix that. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: www.atriumaparthotel.pl/htaccess.txt

Comment: I found how to do that:

RewriteRule ^pl/linki\.htm$ http://ww.atriumaparthotel.pl/pl/linki [R=301,L]

and it works well. It's better to user Rewriterule than Redirect.

Best regards, and many thanks for help and your time!

/Neferith